# adjusting css font size by vh and vw

Tags: html, css, font-size, viewport-units

So I have text that I want to automatically resize based on the size of its container. However if I use something like

```
font-size: 5vw;
```

it looks good, but when I shrink the page the height starts getting way too small

Is there anyway that I can resize the text based on both vh and vw so, for example, if I just decrease the width of the page the height doesn't decrease too?

like if I only decrease the width of the page, I want the height of the text to stay the same and vice versa.

Basically I want the text to always fit inside the box perfectly and have same proportions no matter what the size of the page/container is?

Is there anyway to base font size on both vh and vw like this in CSS/HTML?

Comment: I don't think a font size based on window size is a good idea... could cause some problems on mobile devices

Comment: Do you want the height of the font to stay the same while the width shrinks? Or, would you be able to use `vmax` for a unit?

Comment: Are you just trying to keep your text from overflowing your container div? Please show us a code example so we can help you?

Comment: basically the site layout is created from JSON configuration and the user can choose what percentage size of the screen to make different div elements. It wont be on mobile but a stand alone terminal /raspberry pi. so I need to be able to adjust the texts size depending on how big the user chooses to make a div element. So what I was saying was I know that I can base it on vw or vh but for example if i use vw and shrink the div section the height shrinks too I want text to be based on both height and width not one or the other

Answer (score 7):

You can look into the `vmin` and `vmax` units.

While `1vw` will return 1% of the viewport width and `1vh` will return 1% of the viewport height, `1vmin` will return 1% of the smallest viewport dimension, be it either the viewport width (`vw`) or its height (`vh`). Equally `1vmax` will return 1% of whichever viewport dimension is the largest.

In order to have a whole container, including its text, to retain its aspect ratio you will have to apply the same kind of unit to both the container dimensions and its font size.

See the following example in full page mode and play around with the window width and height:

```css
p {
  width: 80vmin;
  font-size: 6vmin;
}
```

```html
<p>Try resizing both the width and height of the output frame. The &lt;p&gt; element and its contents will both respond to whichever dimension is the smallest.</p>
```

**Note**

Internet Explorer 11 and Edge 12 does not support the `vmax` unit. More on browser support [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).

Answer (score 0):

I have been using vw for some time now. I typically use a larger vw for the mobile first (anything under about a 700px viewport). I then adjust everything above that 700px viewport to one a size fits all vw value. That coupled with bootstrap's ease of use flexbox classes gives much less overhead to the css content.