# Applying both vh / vw or percentage to control height and width of text

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive, viewport-units

Is there a way to control the aspect ratio of text so that it always stays the same relative size inside an HTML element and maintains the same aspect ratio, no matter what size its container has?

Is there a way I can control the height AND width of a text using `vw` or `vh`? I have tried percentages, and it doesn't seem to work as it just seems to increase the basic font size by that percentage.

I would like to be to keep the aspect ratio of the text relative to its container the same no matter how much that box is stretched, etc.

It needs to be dynamic, but if I use `vw` for example, and decrease the height, the text will eventually overrun outside of the height of its container, I need the text to be responsive to both height and width changes, not one or the other.

So I am trying to ask if there is a way to control the height and width of a text with `vw` and `vh` or percentages, or a way to do it with JavaScript that will automatically size text based on container size?

I checked out https://github.com/nbrunt/TextFit, but to use the best fit function from there, the container apparently has to have "absolute" values, such as setting them in pixels, while my container size is based on percentage of screen size.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adjusting css font size by vh and vw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47680214/adjusting-css-font-size-by-vh-and-vw)

Answer (score 1):

You might try `vmin` (Equal to the smaller of vw and vh.) or `vmax` (Equal to the larger of vw and vh).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

Check out this [demo](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/RpKEzV?editors=1100).